# What is the difference between a texture pack and a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is a resource pack and what is it's difference between a texture pack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A texture pack was used in previous versions of the game, prior to version 1.6.1, and **only changed the in-game textures of the game.**

In 1.6.1, resource packs were added, which allowed **alternate sounds, music, particle effects and much more to be altered in game, in addition to modifying block, item, and entity textures.**